# VS Code Remote SSH does not write with group permission

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-permissions, vscode-remote

VS Code seems to be unable to write a file of which I am not the owner, but for which my group has write permissions.

- My user is part of the group `www-data` (`usermod -aG www-data $USER`)
- The folder `/tmp/test` has group owner `www-data` and flag `g+s`:

```
$ls -la /tmp
drwxrwsr--  2 user www-data    4096 Aug 19 14:30 test
```

- A file in the folder is owned by user `www-data`, group `www-data` and has mode `775`.

```
$ls -la test
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Aug 19 14:32 t
```

When I try to edit the file through Putty, everything works fine

```
$ echo "Test" > t; cat t
Test
```

but when I edit the file through VS code I get

`Failed to save 't': Unable to write file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+example.com/tmp/test/t' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/test/t')`

Is this a bug in VS Code or in my setup?